# Transformation of C code to only use goto

Tags: c, goto

I have the following C code :

```
void BubbleSort(int a[], int array_size)
{
    int i, j, temp;
    for (i = 0; i < (array_size - 1); ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < array_size - 1 - i; ++j)
        {
            if (a[j] > a[j+1])
            {
                temp = a[j+1];
                a[j+1] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I rewrite this code in terms of `goto` only ?

Comment: Wait..am I reading it correctly? You willingly want to add some `goto` statement?

Comment: `goto` is not a function, it's a statement to jump to some label.

Comment: We are going to replace you with a goto function. You're welcome.

Comment: is it an academic interest?

Comment: What else can you use in addition to `goto`?

Comment: I don't see why a goto statement would be need for a simple bubble sort algorithm. You can maybe try rewriting your algorithm using a while loop and a flag to indicate if there are anymore needed permutations to sort your array...

Comment: "How do I rewrite this code in terms of goto only" - remove the for loops and replace them with if-tests, gotos,  target labels, and increments.  yeah, its that simple. and you'll hopefully appreciate structure loops when you're done with it and gaze at both versions side by side. Maybe fix the code to include swap detection, that way it isn't lying with its claimed name.

Comment: Breaking news! [Goto considered harmful!](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html) Mankind discovered this before landing on the moon.

Comment: goto some other site

Answer (score 7):

Since semantics of `while` and `for` changed a little in C++ comparing to C, I think it's OK to refer C++ standard. It provides straight rules on how `for` and `while` are convertible to `goto` (they discussed in section 6.5):

#### while

`while (T t = x) statement` is equivalent to

```
label:
{
    T t = x;
    if (t) {
        statement
        goto label;
    }
}
```

#### for

`for (for-init-statement; condition; expression) statement`  is equivalent to

```
{
    for-init-statement
    while ( condition ) {
        statement
        expression ;
    }
}
```

Thus it equivalent to:

```
{
    for-init-statement
    label:
    if ( condition ) {
        statement
        expression ;
        goto label;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
void BubbleSort(int a[], int array_size)
{
    int i, j, temp;

    // for (i = 0; i < (array_size - 1); ++i)
    i = 0;
BEGINFOR:
    if (i >= (array_size - 1)) goto ENDFOR;

    // for (j = 0; j < array_size - 1 - i; ++j)
    j = 0;
BEGININNERFOR:
    if (j >= array_size - 1 - i) goto ENDINNERFOR;

    if (a[j] > a[j+1])
    {
        temp = a[j+1];
        a[j+1] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
    }

    ++j;
    goto BEGININNERFOR;
ENDINNERFOR:

    ++i;
    goto BEGINFOR;
ENDFOR:
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Quentin ... and yes! I am in the middle of changing batch files and didn't fully switch gears when writing my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

To completely remove all blocks but the code looks ugly compared to the original one IMHO

```
void BubbleSort(int a[], int array_size)
{
    int i, j, temp;

    // for (i = 0; i < (array_size - 1); ++i)
    i = 0;
    BEGINFOR:
    if (i >= (array_size - 1)) goto ENDFOR;

    // for (j = 0; j < array_size - 1 - i; ++j)
    j = 0;
    BEGININNERFOR:
    if (j >= array_size - 1 - i) goto ENDINNERFOR;

    if (a[j] <= a[j+1]) goto ENDOFCOMPARISON
    temp = a[j+1];
    a[j+1] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
    EDNOFCOMPARISON:
    ++j;
    goto BEGININNERFOR;
   ENDINNERFOR:
   ++i;
   goto BEGINFOR;
   ENDFOR:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ehm.. You shouldn't really be using goto. Ever. At all.
The sturcture is

```
i = 0;
label:
//loop action here
i++;
if (i < somevalue)
goto label;
```

Here's your code...

```
void BubbleSort(int a[], int array_size)
{
    int i, j, temp;
    i=0;
    first_loop:
        j = 0;
        second_loop:
            if (a[j] > a[j+1])
            {
                temp = a[j+1];
                a[j+1] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
            j++;
            if (j < array_size - 1 - 1) {
                goto second_loop;
            }
         i++;
         if (i < array_size - 1) {
            goto first_loop;
        }
}
```

Comment: You code is not safe. In case array_size <= 1 you will perform bad memory accesses due to your tests at the end of the loop. You also forgot to remove the second for instruction

Comment: Ye fixed, the extra for statement. Yeah, you shouldn't be invoking the function with array_size = 0, but I can't be bothered to fix that